# Jenkins stash not stashing files

Tags: jenkins

I need to stash 2 ear files to be unstashed in the next stage.
This is my code to stash the files.

steps {
                sh 'chmod +x gradlew'
                echo "Building tms-load and tms-loadRemote ear files"

```
            script {
                sh "./gradlew -PjdkHome=${env.JAVA_HOME} -PweblogicHome=${WEBLOGIC_PATH} -Penv=at2 buildAll"
            }
            stash includes: "./build/staging/deploy/tms/AT2/*", name: "tmsLoadEars"
        }
```

There are 2 ear files in this directory.
The gradle successfully builds the files.
The ant echo shows this:

> [ant:echo] Deploying to ear area
>   'build/staging/deploy/tms/AT2/tms-load'.

The file name is 'tms-load.ear'

When I try to unstash and deploy, I get the error that there were no files included in the stash.
This is my unstash code:

```
script {
                    println JAVA_BIN_PATH;
                    dir('.') {
                        unstash "tmsLoadEars"
                    }
                    sh '''
                    . ~/.bash_profile

                    pghAdminConsole="<server url set here>"
                    wlLevel="L0"
                    "${JAVA_BIN_PATH}"/java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -cp "${WEBLOGIC_PATH}"/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer \
                        -debug -stage -remote -verbose -upload \
                        -source ./build/staging/deploy/tms/AT2/tms-load.ear \
                        -targets $cluster -adminurl t3://$pghAdminConsole \
                        -username <username here> -password <password here> -deploy
                    '''                   
                }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please post the output of `ls build/staging/deploy/tms/AT2/` just before you `stash`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment I was able to solve the issue with the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added stash to the gradle command:

```
steps {
                sh 'chmod +x gradlew'
                echo "Building tms-load and tms-loadRemote ear files"

                script
                {
                    sh "./gradlew -PjdkHome=${env.JAVA_HOME} -PweblogicHome=/opt/weblogic/wl12.1.3.0/wlserver -Penv=at2 buildAll"
                }
                stash name: 'loadEarL0', includes: '**/tms-load.ear'
                stash name: 'loadRemoteEarL0', includes: '**/tms-loadRemote.ear'
            }
```

Then unstashed in the next step:

```
unstash "loadEarL0"
```

Defined the source switch in the Deploy program like this:

```
-source ./build/staging/deploy/tms/AT2/app/tms-load.ear \
```